# Bucketing vs Filters in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm building an app which works like this: the user of the app is the manager of a team, he/she asks some questions to the team and collects the data in the app. Monthly, a report is generated by using this data. There is no use case/scenario where user will need to see all data at once, i.e. not filtered by month.

That being said, I thought about modelling the data this way:

```
 - persons/{personId}:
   - name

 - answersByPerson/{personId}:
   - personName
   - byMonth/{YYYYMM}: (using month as key)
     - month
     - collectedAnswers/{uuid}:
       - answer_to_q1 ... (these are all yes or no questions)
       _ answer_to_qn

 - aggregationsByPerson/{personId}: (this should be computed by cloud function)
   - month
   - byMonth/{YYYYMM}: (also using month as key)
     - sum_q1... (count amount answered with 'yes')
     - sum_qn

 - reportByPerson/{personId}:
   - personName
   - month
   - score (computed from aggregations)
```

So I have these questions:

1. Is it bad for me to use year/month as keys to my documents? (I'd make sure in my app to overwrite data if the key exists)
2. Is it bad for me to reuse the personId as keys in answersByPerson collection? The idea is that I wouldn't have to fetch the persons collection, nor filter the answer collection by personId.
3. Is it overengineering for me to use monthly buckets? I thought that maybe I'd save some money if I fetched `collection('answersByPerson').doc('$personId').collection($month)` instead of fetching `collection('answersByPerson').doc('$personId').where(...)`.
4. Also, would it make sense for me to put the aggregations inside the answers collection? Would I be able to updated it without using a cloud function, or could this lead to issues with synchronization?

edit: I've searched about this and it seems that the term "bucketing" is not that common, I've taken it from this [article](https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-firestore-nosql-data-structure-examples/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3. Firestore charges for the number of documents read, and the bandwidth consumed; it does explicitly not charge for the number of documents it has to search through. If you can write a query to get exactly the documents you need from the combined collection, then the cost will be exactly the same between these two operations. More uniquely: so will the performance, as Firestore's performance depends only on the amount of data you retrieve and not on the size of the collection.

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly, how can it be that filtering a list with e.g. 3000 documents to retrieve 30 of them is as fast as retrieving a collection containing these 30 specific documents? Shouldn't one be O(N) and the other O(1)? Even if in the end I get charged the same?

Comment: It's the magic of Firestore's indexing strategy, and also the reason why it doesn't support many of the types of queries you may be used to from other databases: all queries on Firestore are O(1). In popular words: search for needles in our haystack depends on the number of needles, and not on the size of the haystack. It's quite magic, so I highly recommend giving it a try: just keep adding docs to the collection (from a different device or a node script), and notice that your server-side query performance remains the same.